# how to make existing tensorflow 2.4 installation to use GPU

Tags: tensorflow

I have python 3.7.6, tensorflow 2.4.1 and keras 2.4.0 successfully installed. The code is working too. I have Nvidia graphic card on my computer. I wanted to make tensorflow use GPU to speed up training. I followed all steps to install CUDA 10.2 and cuDNN 8.0.4 as given in various internet blogs. Installation is successful. Path variable is updated correctly. But tensorflow still does not recognize GPU.
The code print(tf.test.is_built_with_cuda()) returns True

But this code:

from tensorflow.python.client import device_lib
print(device_lib.list_local_devices

returns

[name: "/device:CPU:0"
device_type: "CPU"
memory_limit: 268435456
locality {
}
incarnation: 9835297869773399600
]

So shows only CPU not GPU. Any help is appeciated

Comment: Please run nvidia-smi and confirm if all in https://www.tensorflow.org/install/gpu have been confirmed. Please check https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/gpu as well if not yet.

Comment: I have confirmed these. Also I installed tensorflow-gpu package also of the same version 2.4.1. Still it does not detect the GPU

Comment: Please add OS in tags as well.

Comment: I had difficulty with this as well. As Marc posted in an answer, it needs CUDA 11. Nvidia has easy directions on its website on how to install that.

Answer (score 0):

According to this list (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/source#gpu) Tensorflow 2.4 requires CUDA 11.

Comment: The fact that this article is out of date does not change the required CUDA version though. I am pretty sure that I was running tensorflow 2.4 with CUDA 11 and it worked fine. So why should it now suddenly work with CUDA 10? I would definetely try using cuda 11, if it does not help one can still continue to search for another reason.

Answer (score 0):

It would be easy to follow the tutorial to install Tensorflow 2.4 with GPU in [here](https://towardsdatascience.com/install-tensorflow-with-cuda-cudnn-and-gpu-support-in-4-easy-steps-954f176daac3)
.

To ensure a smooth installation, I would also advise creating a virtual environment, and ensuring you are following the installation after activating it. In addition, make sure you use the virtual env in your project.

Comment: This article is out of date. Anaconda now [packages](https://anaconda.org/anaconda/tensorflow-gpu) `tensorflow-gpu` 2.4.1.